# Google Script - Remove duplicates in last 15 rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have refer this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) to remove duplicates in my whole google spread sheet, but it takes much time when the sheet contains large amount of data. Because of that I need to remove duplicates(keep only one record) in last 15 non empty rows.

This is the code.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11SbGOCZDiTc21Jjnh7r4XW43QNtdV2L0fGdzHDxRvdA');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
 var first = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 first.clearContents();
 first.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised as requested to compare duplicates based on the first two columns and having columns A to E:

```
function removeDuplicatesRev() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet =ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  var lc=sheet.getLastColumn()
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc).getValues();//Changed to get all columns
  var newData = new Array();
  var alen=data.length
  var adjlen=alen-15
    for(i=adjlen;i<alen;i++){
      var row = data[i];
      var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
       if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1]){ //changed to compare col A&B
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
 var clr =sheet.getRange(adjlen+1, 1, 15, sheet.getLastColumn())
 clr.clearContent()
 sheet.getRange(adjlen+1, 1, newData.length,   newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Could you help me to limit only to first 2 columns?

Comment: I mean, looking duplicates only in first 2 columns

Comment: Could you give an example? I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I have 5 columns, Lets say A,B,C,D and E. When looking for duplicates I want to compare only using column A and B. If one row contains value A = 5 and B =3, Any other row cant contains that. But C, D, E values can be same or differ (no need to concern about those columns). First original row should keep and other rows should remove.